# How to handle the changing size of for loop when selecting a value from ComboBox

Tags: java

I have this piece of code for a combobox value selection. It works well when the size of combobox stays static but there are few combo boxes wherein selecting the value from the list removes the value from the List and the size of combo-box is reduced by one for each selection.

How do I handle the reducing size for the loop?

```
public dropdownSelection(Elements elements, String value) {

    for (Element ele : elements) {
        elements.reloadElements();
        if (ele.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            ele.verify(60).present().click();
            break;
        } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("All")) {
            ele.verify(60).present().click();
        } else if (value.contains("#")) {
            String[] stringValues = value.trim().split("#");
            for (int i = 0; i < stringValues.length; i++) {
                if (stringValues[i].equals(ele.getText())) {
                    ele.verify(60).present().click();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Value:

- Case 1: Select a particular element
- Case 2: Select all the elements
- Case 3: Select all the elements which are separated by #

The above code executes the first loop properly but for second run onwards it doesn't since the size of the for loop got reduced by 1 and it keeps hitting back the first element again.

Comment: Can you share some more details? It seems if you keep removing element  "ele" form the list, it might help. share a complete test case example. why do you need to run it multiple times?

Comment: "elements.reloadElements();"  don't do that... you are affecting your iterator.  You need to re-get the references after any change to the DOM.  (your find elements call...)  Selenium will alert you to this by throwing a "Stale Element" exception.